# What is the best way to resolve di conflicts in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, di

It's pretty easy to replace a class in Magento 2 using dependency injection. However, let's say I have two modules that want to replace the same class. For example, the [dotmailer Magento2 extension](https://github.com/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension) sets a preference for `Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement` but my own team's modules already override that class with one of our own. How do we resolve this conflict?

Comment: Use plugins and observers :)

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau That doesn't work when the methods that need changing are private or protected - which is, unfortunately, a lot of the time.

Comment: If the method is private you should not change it anyway.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau Private and protected methods can be wrong/inappropriate/buggy/defective just as much as public methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the same problem like in M1 if modules overwrite the same class. You've to implement your own class which consolidate the changes of all conflicting modules in order to resolve it.

**Your basic module structure**

```
- app/code/YourNamespace
   |- ConflictResolver
        |- etc
        |   |- module.xml
        |   |- di.xml
        |- Model
        |   |- YourClass.php
        |- composer.json
        |- registration.php
```

Your module structure should look something like this. The third party and Magento modules are located in vendor directory... If not see here for how to setup a Magento 2 project: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install_ce.html

In the `module.xml` you have to define the sequence for your module loading

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd"> 
    <module name="YourNamespace_ConflictResolver" setup_version="1.0.0"> 
        <sequence>
            <module name="ThirdParty_ModuleA" />
            <module name="ThirdParty_ModuleB" />
            <module name="Magento_ModuleA" />
        </sequence>
    </module> 
</config>
```

In this example your module would be loaded after the three modules listed in the `sequence` node and your DI config will overrule the previous loaded...

See this page for more details: 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html

However this is not the preferred way of the Magento Engineers. Plugins have better compatibility and if a module overwrites by using preferences this is a sign for less quality... Of course I understand, that there is in some cases no other way because the core it self does not follow Magento 2 standards in most modules.

**The Future...**

I've told with some core developers about further engineering ideas and concepts. The new way to go will be that all modules will be separate into API / service contracts and (final; final is not really possible because of the autogenerated classes) implementation so there will be interfaces for everything, but you can't extend from core and have to implement your own logic... For your problem this would mean that you have to implement an own class which includes the right interface(s) anyway...

Edit: Alan Kent just published something about this: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Service-Contracts-in-Separate-Packages/ba-p/68129

Comment: "Implement your own class to consolidate the changes of all conflicting modules" - that sounds reasonable - a conflict-resolution module that resolves conflicts between two fighting modules? Am I reading you correctly?

Comment: Yes, you do. I updated my answer in order to be more concrete, so I hope...

Comment: I'm new to Magento - is it possible for you to expand in your answer how to structure the module so that its consolidation class gets loaded instead of the two classes it's mediating? Or should I post that as a new question?

Comment: I'll try :) But currently I've only my smartphone, so you have to way till tomorrow...

Comment: Wow, excellent edit to this answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Make your class extend the dot mailer one. And declare your module to be loaded after the dot mailer module in module.xml.

Comment: Okay, I guess that works in the simple example I posted, but what about if I have two third-party modules overriding the same class? Or if extending a third-party module's class isn't feasible?

Comment: Then I guess the modules are not compatible.

Comment: So short of making one module depend on the other, there's no other solution for this?

Comment: Not that I know of. But there might be. Wait for an other answer. Don't take mine for granted.

Comment: Thanks. I was going to wait anyway, since your answer's just bad news :)

Comment: Sorry. Don't shoot the messenger. :)

Comment: @Marius, I have installed Layered Navigation and Ajax filter, so how to avoid this conflict?